# Is it legal, with no licensure, to sell subscriptions to a blog offering opinions on future stock prices, even if the opinions are non-individualized?

Tags: united-states, finance, sec

To elaborate, let us take an instance where price predictions would be derived from computer models, and where predictions are disclaimed as being "opinions rather than financial advice".

Would this construction be sufficient to skirt being classified as a financial advisor by U.S. municipal or federal government?

[Another question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/66983/is-it-legal-to-sell-stock-market-predictions-online) was asked that was largely similar to this one, but its answer was unclear as to whether licensure was required in the event that the price prediction opinions are not granted on an individual basis and are rather accessible as part of a broader subscription to a blog/publishing platform.

SeekingAlpha offers a subscription for information, without referencing licensed individuals when selling it. And it is doubtful that its 16k contributors it vaunts are licensed either.

Comment: The primary issue is whether you have to be a registered investment advisor. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/ria.asp